# How To Divide Amount To Dynamic Parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, vb.net

I have a problem with some calculation regarding how to divide such amount into dynamic parameter. Let I show the 2 scenario below:-

I have dynamic label like XT and XO where XO should be half from XT after amount a divide.

```
Scenario 1:
Amount = 200
XT = 100
XT = 100

Scenario 2:
Amount = 200
XO = 50
XO = 50
XT = 100
```

This label XO and XT are dynamic where can be add more or delete, than I need do recalculation again.

Please help me regarding this matter either on .net or javascript.

Comment: what about xt is it dynamic too? and also what is rule followed in dividing the amount?

Comment: Why have you specified three different languages here? Which one are you *actually* interested in? And which part of the problem is causing you issues? Is it creating these labels, or the arithmetic? If it's the arithmetic, it sounds like you just need `v = amount / (xo + 2 * xt)` and then set the value in each `xo` label to `v`, and the value in each `xt` label to `2 * v`... but basically, it's very unclear what kind of answer you're looking for.

Comment: I just have this task and I need to create form actually on asp.net. I think on front should be html and javascript then I need to post all this to codebehind.<br/> @user2181397 - label XT or XO are dynamic where I can change it and I can add more label and assign either XT or XO. <br> Jon Skeet your formula I will try and see how it show a result <br> Thanks you both for quick reply and I appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this small logical to do that, the rest you should do you self.

Let me show my syntax on javascript what I know:-

```
            ttrans = (Number(tfull) * 2) + (Number(thalf) * 1);
            dfamt = Number(damt) / Number(ttrans)*2;
            dhamt = Number(dfamt) / 2;
```

Let me explain what are variable stand for

1. tfull is your total count XT, u need to count how many XT are appear
2. thalf is your total count XO
3. ttrans is total (XT*2) + (X0*1) - u need that
4. dfamt is amount should be assign to XT
5. dhamt is amount should be assign to XO

That all for the calculation and assign each value even your XT or XO are dynamic OR your amount are change this syntax above will help you re-calculate.

Comment: Awesome! your syntax are clean and your explanation make me know what happen. That means I just assign a value dfamt to XT and dhamt to XO. Wow... so simple that. Thanks you so much sir!.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand on your scenario is how you can determine how many XT and XO before you do calculation and assign value for each based conditions (XO half from XT). You cannot do calculation before you count how many XT and XO because as you said label XT and XO can be add more or delete.

Comment: You are rights. My XT or X0 are dynamic means can be added on runtime. I will think on that later.

Comment: * I will think how to create function create dynamic objects. If you can help me I am so please.. :)